# Do Wii U PAL consoles from Asia work with Wii U PAL games from Europe

Tags: wii-u

I purchased a Wii U (PAL) from United Arab Emirates.  Am I limited to buying games for it that originated in that country or can I buy say, UK games?

Comment: Well, if it's really a PAL console, you should be able to play every PAL game. BUT I would test it first - do you have a friend or a place where you can lend a game?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

as long as your Wii U is a PAL console, it can play any Wii U PAL game, as the PAL region is one single region.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your Wii U will play any region game which works on PAL systems.

Comment: This question isn't asking about PAL to NTSC.  It's asking about a PAL console playing PAL games from a different region.

Comment: i answered it will play any region game. only this can't play region:america games

Comment: According to your answer, the Wii will only play European and Asian games.  This console comes from the United Arab Emirates; how does that work with only Europe and Asian games?

Comment: lol. srry i didnt checked my answer. i tried to say what i replied to you. sorry.i will fix that

Comment: To be clear, are talking about the original Wii or the Wii U?